# Allowing files with proper names using Regex

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here are different files and the output which should look like:

1. abc.csv - Correct
2. abc.csv.gz - Fail
3. abc.csv.csv - Fail
4. abc.def.csv - Correct

The present regex looks like `.*[.]csv$` which passes cases 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4. I tried using {} and \B to allow only 1 extension but wasn't able to make it correctly.

Comment: would `abc.def.csv` be correct? what about simply `filename.endswith('.csv')`?

Comment: @mozway yes, but I want to use regex and not python, as I am using it in snowflake

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it does not work in the cases like abc.def.csv

Comment: is this python or not? Why did you have the `python` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, `filename.endswith('.csv')` is in my opinion the most pythonic option.

That said, if you want to use a regex, you can use `re.match('.*(?<!\.csv)(\.csv)$', s)` or `re.fullmatch('.*(?<!\.csv)(\.csv)', s)`

```
s = 'abc.csv.csv'
re.match('.*(?<!\.csv)(\.csv)$', s)
# no match

s = 'abc.def.csv'
re.match('.*(?<!\.csv)(\.csv)$', s)
#<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='abc.def.csv'>
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V1i4HC/1)